# dual to Hodge theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory, calculus-of-variations

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold.

In my understanding Hodge theory shows that any de Rham cohomology class can be represented uniquely by a harmonic form. Moreover the harmonic form minimizes some energy.

Is there a dual version of this story?

By theorems of Thom we know that any rational homology class is represented by a submanifold. Does the choice of a Riemannian metric allow us to search for a best representative (one which is totally geodesic or ...)? Playing around with the torus makes me doubt this. There seem to be many choices of best representative in a given homology class. On the other hand there are many representatives that I would discard as best as well: For example all the non-geodesic ones. Is there something which one can say?

Comment: Very interesting question. I've asked a similar one some time ago, but got no answer. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229527/the-metric-gives-the-optimal-element-in-a-class

Comment: How about minimal volume representatives? See e.g. this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283259/smallest-volume-representatives-of-homology

Comment: @j.c.: Thank you, this might be what I am looking for.

Comment: @ThomasRot OK, I may try to write an answer from that point of view in a few days.

Comment: @j.c. But there is in the end no uniqueness right? So I know there is a current with minimal volume, but there might be many.

Comment: in symplectic context, i think Smith--Yau proved that a Hamiltonian isotopy class of Lagrangian tori in closed CY manifold contains at most one Special Lagrangian representative